# Collect template parameters at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

I have a class which takes many other classes as template arguments (for compile-time grammar generation with [TAO PEGTL](https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL) if it matters) and would like to know if there is a better and more extensible way to do this, than typing everything manually.

**Current Situation:**

```
//Class1.h
class Class1 {}
...
//ClassN.h
class ClassN {}

//Collection.h
struct collectionClass : templateClass<Class1,...,ClassN>

//SpecificTemplate.h
template<> struct specificClass<Class1>{
   //Do the same
}
...
template<> struct specificClass<ClassN>{
   //Do the same
}
```

Currently this has to be done manually (and in multiple locations for different "collection" classes).

Is there a way to change this into a better manageable alternative like:

**Desired Situation:**

```
//Class1.h
class Class1 {}
REGISTER_CLASS(Class1)
...
//ClassN.h
class ClassN {}
REGISTER_CLASS(ClassN)

//Collection.h
struct collectionClass : templateClass<REGISTERED_CLASSES>

//SpecificTemplate.h
CREATE_CLASSES_FROM_REGISTERED()
```

I was trying to achieve this with boost PP and MPL for the last days but I'm not sure if it is possible at all.

**EDIT:**

Specific instances are required by pegtl like this:
There are actions which are predefined as:

```
template<typename Rule>
struct Action : tao::pegtl::nothing<Rule> {
};
```

And have to be instantiated as:

```
template<>
struct Action<specificRule> {
  static void apply0(State &state) {
    state.rule = specificRule::ID;
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need to do this over just specifying `template<class T> struct specificClass<T> { /*Do the same*/ };`? If all these instantiations are identical then I don't see the purpose of spelling each one out. If they are different, how would `CREATE_CLASSES_FROM_REGISTERED` know what to change?

Comment: Because /*Do the same*/ will do something with T itself.
Like call T.method(). Which is the same for all classes, but has to specifically instantiated for the grammar framework.

Comment: You can literally use `T.method()` just fine (if all classes have a `method()`)... Maybe you could make the example more specific?

Comment: So what you need is explicit instantiation? Of `specificClass` or of some templated thing in `ClassX`?

Comment: Edited Question with more specific information

Comment: What `REGISTER_CLASS` do? This smells like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), since you are asking how to fix solution and you didn't not describe details of the problem you are trying to solve. I'm suspecting that you need some kind of meta data about the class. Is this what you need?

Comment: I want to reduce the requirement to manually write the same code for each class every time.

This is used for dynamic functions, of which many will be implemented.

Currently the time required to write the actual function is way less than the time required to write all the "support" code which is the same for each class (but distributed over many files)
So what I want is (most probably) some kind of metaprograming to generate the support code.

Comment: Are you looking for a partial specialization? That could give a group of classes share a specific instantiation of specificClass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Registration of rules

I recommend an explicit manual registration of all "rules" (`Class1`, ..., `ClassN`) in a single place of your codebase:

```
// foo_rule.hpp
#pragma once
struct FooRule {};

// bar_rule.hpp
#pragma once
struct BarRule {};

// foobar_rule.hpp
#pragma once
struct FoobarRule {};

// registered_rules.hpp
#pragma once
#include <tuple>
#include "foo_rule.hpp"
#include "bar_rule.hpp"
#include "foobar_rule.hpp"
using RegisteredRules = std::tuple<FooRule, BarRule, FoobarRule>;
```

The mechanism above is very obvious to anyone who reads the code: We can be absolutely sure which rules are registered.

A downside is clearly the separation of rule definition and rule registration: Adding a new rule called, say, `SuperRule` requires two steps:

1. define `struct SuperRule{};` in "super_rule.hpp"
2. append `SuperRule` to the list of `RegisteredRules` in "registered_rules.hpp".

There is obviously the danger to forget step 2. If you wish then you can invent a mechanism that protects against this mistake, but let us focus on the remaining part of your question.

## Inherit from a wrapper which wraps all registered rules

You are asking for a strategy to generate this code:

```
struct FirstCollection : TemplateClass<FooRule, BarRule/*, ...*/> {};
struct SecondCollection : TemplateClass<FooRule, BarRule/*, ...*/> {};
// where /*, ...*/ refers to all remaining rules which have been registered
```

Let us use a primitive called, say, `rewrap` for this. The code which generates the above inheritance then reads

```
struct FirstCollection : rewrap<RegisteredRules, TemplateClass> {};
struct SecondCollection : rewrap<RegisteredRules, TemplateClass> {};
```

Obviously, `rewrap` should "inject" the variadic type parameters of its first input into its second input:

```
template<class OldWrapped, template<class...> class NewWrapper>
using rewrap = /* to be implemented */

static_assert(
  std::is_same<
    rewrap<std::pair<int, double>, std::tuple>,
    std::tuple<int, double>
  >{}
);

static_assert(
  std::is_same<
    rewrap<std::tuple<char, long>, std::pair>,
    std::pair<char, long>
  >{}
);
```

## Specialize `Action` for registered rules

In your question you ask how to **specialize** a templated class `Action` for all registered rules:

```
template<>
struct Action<FooRule>{
  static void apply0(State& state) {
    // do the same
  }
}
/*...*/
template<>
struct Action<FoobarRule>{
  static void apply0(State& state) {
    // do the same
  }
}
```

Instead, I suggest to use **partial specialization**. Let us assume you are allowed to add a second template parameter to `Action`:

```
template<class Rule>
struct Nothing {
  static void apply0(State&) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }
};

template<
  class Rule,
  class Enable = void
> struct Action
  : Nothing<Rule>
{};
```

The second template parameter can be used to play the common SFINAE game:

```
template<
  class SpecificRule
> struct Action<
  SpecificRule,
  std::enable_if_t<
    is_wrapped_in<SpecificRule, RegisteredRules>// to be implemented
  >
> {
  static void apply0(State&) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }
};
```

What you obviously need is another primitive called `is_wrapped_in`.

## Full example in C++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// rewrap

namespace detail {

template<
  class OldWrapped,
  template<class...> class NewWrapper
> struct Rewrap;

template<
  template<class...> class OldWrapper,
  class... Wrappees,
  template<class...> class NewWrapper
> struct Rewrap<
  OldWrapper<Wrappees...>,
  NewWrapper
> {
  using T = NewWrapper<Wrappees...>;
};

}// detail

template<class OldWrapped, template<class...> class NewWrapper>
using rewrap = typename detail::Rewrap<OldWrapped, NewWrapper>::T;

static_assert(
  std::is_same<
    rewrap<std::pair<int, double>, std::tuple>,
    std::tuple<int, double>
  >{}
);

static_assert(
  std::is_same<
    rewrap<std::tuple<char, long>, std::pair>,
    std::pair<char, long>
  >{}
);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// is_wrapped_in

namespace detail {

template<class T, class Wrapped>
struct IsWrappedIn;

template<class T, template<class...> class Wrapper, class... Wrappees>
struct IsWrappedIn<T, Wrapper<Wrappees...>>
  : std::bool_constant<(... || std::is_same<T, Wrappees>{})>
{};

}// detail

template<class T, class Wrapped>
constexpr bool is_wrapped_in = detail::IsWrappedIn<T, Wrapped>::value;

static_assert(is_wrapped_in<int, std::tuple<char, char, int, long>> == true);
static_assert(is_wrapped_in<int, std::tuple<char, char, long, long>> == false);
static_assert(is_wrapped_in<int, std::pair<int, int>> == true);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// registered_rules

struct UnregisteredRule {};

struct FooRule {};
struct BarRule {};
struct FoobarRule {};

using RegisteredRules = std::tuple<FooRule, BarRule, FoobarRule>;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// collections

template<class... Rules>
struct TemplateClass {
  using Root = TemplateClass<Rules...>;// convenience alias for derived classes
};

struct FirstCollection : rewrap<RegisteredRules, TemplateClass> {};
struct SecondCollection : rewrap<RegisteredRules, TemplateClass> {};

static_assert(
  std::is_same<
    FirstCollection::Root,
    TemplateClass<FooRule, BarRule, FoobarRule>
  >{}
);

static_assert(
  std::is_same<
    SecondCollection::Root,
    TemplateClass<FooRule, BarRule, FoobarRule>
  >{}
);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// action

struct State {};

template<class Rule>
struct Nothing {
  static void apply0(State&) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }
};

template<
  class Rule,
  class Enable = void
> struct Action
  : Nothing<Rule>
{};

template<
  class SpecificRule
> struct Action<
  SpecificRule,
  std::enable_if_t<
    is_wrapped_in<SpecificRule, RegisteredRules>
  >
> {
  static void apply0(State&) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main() {
  State state{};

  Action<UnregisteredRule>::apply0(state);

  Action<FooRule>::apply0(state);
  Action<BarRule>::apply0(state);
  Action<FoobarRule>::apply0(state);
}
```

Output with GCC 8.2.0:

```
static void Nothing<Rule>::apply0(State&) [with Rule = UnregisteredRule]
static void Action<SpecificRule, typename std::enable_if<is_wrapped_in<SpecificRule, std::tuple<FooRule, BarRule, FoobarRule> >, void>::type>::apply0(State&) [with SpecificRule = FooRule]
static void Action<SpecificRule, typename std::enable_if<is_wrapped_in<SpecificRule, std::tuple<FooRule, BarRule, FoobarRule> >, void>::type>::apply0(State&) [with SpecificRule = BarRule]
static void Action<SpecificRule, typename std::enable_if<is_wrapped_in<SpecificRule, std::tuple<FooRule, BarRule, FoobarRule> >, void>::type>::apply0(State&) [with SpecificRule = FoobarRule]
```

Comment: This looks really promising.
I'll play around with this example later today.
Thank you already for this attempt.

Comment: @NSchaef: Updated with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much you can change your code but... if you can **numerate** the classes `Class1`, `Class2`, ... `ClassN` making they specialization of a template class `ClassX`

```
// class_base.h (additional header)
template <std::size_t>
struct ClassX;
```

so that `Class1` become `ClassX<1u>`, `Class2` become `ClassX<2u>`, etc

```
// class1.h
template <>
struct ClassX<1u>
 { };

// class2.h
template <>
struct ClassX<2u>
 { };

// a file for ClassX<3>, one for ClassX<4>, etc
```

you can make so that your `collectionclass` can inherit from all `classX` specialization -- if their number are sequential and if you register the number of `classX` specialization classes -- using a class helper, `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence` (available starting from C++14)

```
static constexpr std::size_t numOfClasses { 2u }; // num of ClassX classes

template <typename...>
struct templateClass
 { };

template <typename>
struct cc_helper;

template <std::size_t ... Is>
struct cc_helper<std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public templateClass<ClassX<Is+1u>...> // +1u if start from `ClassX<1u>
 { };                                       // without +1u is start from
                                            // ClassX<0u>

struct collectionclass
   : public cc_helper<std::make_index_sequence<numOfClasses>>
 { };
```

Now, in specifictemplate.h, you can simply write (if I understand correctly and all `specificClass` are substantially equal)

```
// specifictemplate.h

template <typename>
struct specificClass;

template <std::size_t I>
struct specificClass<ClassX<I>>
 {
   //Do the same only one time
 };
```

Comment: As far as I understand, the question is about automatically generating template specializations of an existing template. The "derive from indexed base class" approach is interesting but not the core of the question I feel (despite what the title suggests - I would have edited already if I had a clearer picture what the goal of all this is).

Comment: @MaxLanghof - as far I understand... I'm really confused about what the OP exactly want. I've understanded that he (she?) want a way to automatically generate a `collectionClass` that inherit from a class that depends from list of registered classes and a list of `specificClass` specializations. But I admit that I'm all but certain about this. Waiting for the OP authentic interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the nifty trick of function-overloading together with the fact that derived types have higher priorities than their base types when performing said overloading.

This will enable you to write:

```
TYPE_COLLECTOR_START(foo);

TYPE_COLLECTOR_ADD(foo, int);
TYPE_COLLECTOR_ADD(foo, std::pair<bool, bool>);
TYPE_COLLECTOR_ADD(foo, char);

TYPE_COLLECTOR_END(foo);

static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<foo, type_collector::list<int, std::pair<bool, bool>, char>>
);
```

This trick is non-standard-compliant as it uses the `__COUNTER__` compiler extension macro, but pretty much all compilers define it.

Basically, you define a `version<N>` class, that inherits from `version<N - 1>` (recursively):

```
template <unsigned long N> struct version : version<N - 1> {};
template <> struct version<0> {};
```

And then you define a list of function overloads with increasing `version` numbers using `__COUNTER__`:

```
// the result is stored in this type
template <class... Ts>
struct list {
    template <class T>
    using add = list<Ts..., T>;
};

// macro TYPE_COLLECTOR_START usage will expand to
auto get(version<0>) -> list<>;

// macro TYPE_COLLECTOR_ADD usages will expand to
auto get(version<1>) -> decltype(get(version<0>{}))::add<int>;
auto get(version<2>) -> decltype(get(version<1>{}))::add<std::pair<bool, bool>>;
auto get(version<3>) -> decltype(get(version<2>{}))::add<char>;

// macro TYPE_COLLECTOR_END usage will expand to
using foo = decltype(get(version<3>{}));
```

Obviously, you'd want to avoid name collisions (and possibly collect types into two different lists at the same time; interleaving), so I've coded a more thorough example for reference.

- Live at https://godbolt.org/g/v4DqDr

### EDIT

For your specific use-case, if I understood you correctly, you could define wrapper macros over what I've provided above that would both add the types to a list and define the specializations:

```
#define REGISTER_RULE(rule)\
    TYPE_COLLECTOR_ADD(registered_rules, rule)\
    \
    template <>\
    struct Action<rule_name> {\
        static void apply0(State& state) {\
            state.rule = rule_name::ID;\
        }\
    }
```

And then you'd have something like:

```
// registered_rules.h
namespace tao_pegtl_namespace { TYPE_COLLECTOR_START(registered_rules); }

// rule1.h
#include "registered_rules.h"
namespace your_namespace { class rule1 {}; }
namespace tao_pegtl_namespace { REGISTER_RULE(your_namespace::rule1); }

// rule2.h
#include "registered_rules.h"
namespace your_namespace { class rule2 {}; }
namespace tao_pegtl_namespace { REGISTER_RULE(your_namespace::rule2); }

// rules_collection.h
namespace tao_pegtl_namespace {
    TYPE_COLLECTOR_END(registered_rules);
    struct rules_collection : templateClass<(unpack `registered_rules`...)> {}
}
```

This doesn't allow you to have a different file (*SpecificTemplate.h* as you called it) that contains all the action specializations. I have no idea what `tao::pegtl` is, so I might be completely off here.